# Get last UNIQUEIDENTIFIER inserted in a table inside a TRIGGER from a SQL 2005 database

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, triggers

I need to be able to monitor a Table and react very time a record is inserted.  This table has no ITN IDENTITY field, only a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as its primary key.  Without any alteration of existing inputs, SPs, etc.  I need to be able to find the last inserted ID from within a trigger.  This is what I have (obviously does not work):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_UserInserted
   ON  Users
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC UserInserted (SELECT User_Id FROM INSERTED);

END
GO
```

Here I am trying to get the User_Id from the last inserted record in the Users table and run it through the UserInserted SP.  Thank you for the help, I am stumped.

HLGEM Made a great point - even on a bulk insert, I only need the last record inserted - I know this is a strange request.

Comment: One reason why your trigger won't work is that you have made the very poor assumption that only one record will be in the inserted table. This is unacceptable in a trigger. 

If there is a multiple record insert do you need all the records run through the  UserInserted stored proc? Or only the last one?

Comment: what would indicate that iti si the last one?

Comment: That is my problem right there... I don't have a datetime or anything to go off of.  Is there anything that I can call in a trigger which will return the last inserted row possibly?

Comment: Are you at least using NEWSEQUENTIALID() to create the GUID?

Comment: No - in some places, they are using NEWID() and in some they are producuing the GUID in the application code - no consistency.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a concept of the last inserted row. You have to something to order on to have the last one in the order. You can cheate somewhat with a windowing function but there is still no guarantee it is the last one if you don't have a nything to order it by.

Comment: I figured a simple solution - I was able to simply add an INT IDENTITY column - now I can use that...

Comment: @naspinski: Sounds like an answer to me, even if it's somewhat specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your trigger to fire INSTEAD OF INSERT. A *uniqueidentifier* variable must be generated using the *NEWID()* function. In the INSERT statement in the trigger body, the columns must be provided in order. Assuming a table defined this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    First int,
    User_Id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY,
    Third int,
    Fourth int)
```

Then the trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_UserInserted ON Users
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @newid uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

INSERT INTO Users
SELECT
    First,
    @newid,
    Third,
    Fourth
FROM inserted

EXECUTE UserInserted(@newid)
-- you can actually provide all the columns to UserInserted

END
```

For this to work properly, make sure that the table does not have a default for the primary key as *NEWID()*.